# Cannot link jemalloc shared library with cmake

Tags: c, cmake

I tried to compile the jemalloc demo using cmake/And here is my initial cmake code.

//brew install jemalloc

```
in CMakeLists

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jemalloc)

in cpp

#include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>
```

Error: cannot include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>

... ok, fine. I try that.

```
in CMakeLists

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jemalloc)
```

make

```
[build] ld: library not found for -ljemalloc
[build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[build] make[3]: *** [demo] Error 1
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/rule] Error 2
```

I don't know what to do?

I tried to compile from the command line.

```
clang -std=c++11 demo.cpp -ljemalloc
```

It's ok....

Maybe I can put some pictures.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6pxg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gArWN.gif)

Comment: Where exactly is the .so (or .a) file located? Btw: In general it's preferred to specify link/include dirs per target using `target_link_directories`/`target_include_directories`

Comment: @fabian /usr/local/lib